# Django authenticate not returning existent users

Tags: python, django, django-forms

My forms.py :

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
 username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs= 
 {'class':'form-control form-control-lg','placeholder':'Username'}))
  password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs= 
 {'class':'form-control form-control-lg','placeholder':'Password'}))

  def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
     username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
     password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")

     if username and password:
         user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

         if user is None:
             raise forms.ValidationError("This user does not exist")
         elif user is not None:
            if not user.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This user is not longer 
          active.")

            elif not user.check_password(password):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect password")

    return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

models.py :

```
class User(AbstractUser):
 is_client = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 is_trainer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 username = models.CharField('username', max_length=150, unique=True)
 email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
 hub = models.ForeignKey(Hub, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, 
 null=True)
 USER_POSITIONS = ((0, 'Not a member'), (1, 'Member'), (2, 'Excom'), 
 (3, 'Leader'))
 hub_position = models.CharField(default='Not Member',max_length=50)
 mentor = models.ForeignKey('self' ,on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
 blank=True,null=True)
 terms = models.BooleanField(blank=True,default=False)
 USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
 REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email','terms']

 def get_absolute_url(self):
     return reverse('student:dashboard', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

I want the user to be redirected to the resend activation link page if he hasnt activated already .Now after i register the user and skip account activation and then try to login ,it shows validation error "This user does not exist" eventhough this user is registered in the User model .

Comment: Can you try `if not user` instead of `if user is None:`?

Comment: Doesnt make any change!I tried @WaqasHamid

Comment: Can you check your database for the user and confirm it exists and is not activated. Also can you cross-check the username and password you're entering?

Comment: Im sure it is all correct @WaqasHamid

Comment: if i do User.objects.filter(username=username,password="Hashed pwd from db") it returns user ..Using authenticate,its always returning none @WaqasHamid

Comment: I will need to see your `User` model to answer this.

Comment: included @WaqasHamid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with the version of Django that you're using.

The more recent versions of Django return users for any authentication, only if `user.is_active=TRUE`

My suggestion to solve this problem would be the use of `CustomUserModel` for your `User`.

I use something like this:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    return True
```

and add `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'` in my `settings.py`

Basically, go for a `CustomUserModel` that suits your needs and that should do it.

Comment: since the project is in updation and already been deployed,i cant risk changing the user model now.

Comment: have to see if there is any other way .

Comment: You can add another field called `is_email_verified` to prevent him from bypassing. That would help. However, I would always recommend using a `CustomUserModel`.